# SQL Server - Inserting default values bcp

Tags: sql-server, identity, bcp

In SQL Server, how to insert default values while using `bcp` command?

Scenario is from the below table, while running `bcp` command, column 'sno' is identity column, where values should increment automatically by 1, data for `values` column should come from datafile and values for `date` column should automatically updated to today's date and values for status column should updated as `Flag1`.

For normal usage I know how to create `bcp` format file. For the above scenario, how can I create a format file and insert data to table1?

Table format:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1] 
(
    SNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    values  varchar(13) NOT NULL,
    date    datetime NOT NULL,
    status  varchar(50)
)
```

`Table1`:

```
sno  |  values  |    date    |  status
-----+----------+------------+--------
1    |  111111  | 2015-08-17 |  Flag1
2    |  222222  | 2015-08-17 |  Flag1
```

Comment: Side note: *please* don't call your columns things like `date` - first of all, it's a **reserved keyword** (for a datatype) in SQL Server 2008 and newer, and secondly, it's not expressive - what date is it?? Use something more meaningful - `OrderDate`, `HireDate` - anything - just not only `date` on itself.... (same applies to `values` or `status` too......)

Comment: here: let me google that for you. I took your question, and this is the first result. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to put `0` as the host column number to avoid a column from being inserted by `bcp`.

So assuming you have a default constraint for your `[date]` column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table1
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table1_Date DEFAULT(SYSDATETIME()) FOR [Date]
```

and somehow you have also set up some way to calculate the `[status]` - then you could use this format file:

```
12.0
4
1    SQLCHAR         0    12   ";"      0    SNo        ""
2    SQLCHAR         0    13   ";"      2    values     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3    SQLDATETIME     0    24   ";"      0    date       ""
4    SQLCHAR         0    50   "\r\n"   0    status     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

and thus you would be really only importing the `[values]` column - the `SNo` is automatically set by SQL Server (identity column), the `[date]` column is automatically set to the current date&time by means of the default constraint - now you'll have to find a way to fill in the `[status]` column upon or after insert!