# Sql bulk insert calculate values at insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, dynamic-values

So data can be imported into SQL Server from .csv files.
[Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

I'm trying to use this to import test data into a database. So I want the dates to be up-to-date. Currently we use .sql files with `getdate()` so after inserting the dates are all newly generated. But when inserting `getdate()` with bulk insert from a .csv file it will just say 'getdate()'. The dates are only an example, I need different rows to be calculated differently. So one date might get 5 added to it, another 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Inserting default values bcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069586/sql-server-inserting-default-values-bcp)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544526/how-do-i-bulk-insert-with-additional-column-showing-filename

Answer (score 1):

Although bulk insert does not let you specify function calls, you could work around the problem by changing your table definition: add `default` constraint to your `date` column, and do not insert anything into it through bulkinsert. This would ensure that SQL Server fills the column by calling `getdate`:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_MyTable_MyDateColumn_GetDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR MyDateColumn
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to insert different dates. It seems this is not possible.

Comment: @MrFox What do you mean by "inserting different dates"? This approach will insert different dates, too, based on the time when the row is inserted. The call to `GETDATE()` is made only when the data being inserted does not provide a value for `MyDateColumn`.

Comment: Within one set of rows the dates for different rows must be different.

Comment: @MrFox How could you achieve this with `GETDATE()`, unless the data changes while your code is performing bulk insert?

Comment: Because we normal insert I can do GETDATE() + 5, GETDATE() + 10 on different records. Also it's really inconvienent to regenerate the .csv file every time it has to be inserted.